# Object based on array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to format my data that looks like that :

```js
const arr = [{
    date: "2020-12-18",
    value: 2000
  },
  {
    date: "2020-12-01",
    value: 2500
  },
  {
    date: "2020-12-18",
    value: 4000
  }
]
```

To something like that :

```js
const newObj = {
  label: ["2020-12-01", "2020-12-18"],
  data: [{
      t: "2020-12-01",
      y: 2500
    },
    {
      t: "2020-12-18",
      y: 6000
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried couple of things but nothing worked, if somebody can help me.

Comment: Sure! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to reduce() by date that give me a new array like this `newArr["2020-12-01","2020-12-18"]` then create  a new object and give it new property 'label' and value 'newArr' but now i'm stuck for the data property. I can't find a way to make it like in the exemple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const arr = [{
    date: "2020-12-18",
    value: 2000
  },
  {
    date: "2020-12-01",
    value: 2500
  },
  {
    date: "2020-12-18",
    value: 4000
  }
]

const output = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc[cur.date]) acc[cur.date] = {t: cur.date, y: cur.value}
  else acc[cur.date].y += cur.value
  return acc;
}, {});

const newObj = {
  label: Object.keys(output),
  data: Object.values(output)
}
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I tried it and this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot ! I don't understand everyting that is happening but I will learn more about `reduce()` to understand it

Comment: Ok I understood everything I will never have find it by myself lol

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Map Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

First, create a new Map Object. Traverse the array using `Array.prototype.forEach()` method. Make `date` as a key and check if key exists by using `Map.prototype.has(key)` method. If key does not exist then set it by calling the `Map.prototype.set(key, value)` method (In this solution, value is an object). If key exists then get the object using `Map.prototype.get(key)` method, then update the object and set it into the Map Object. At last, for label get all the keys using `Map.prototype.keys()` and for data get all the values using `Map.prototype.values()` method.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    date: '2020-12-18',
    value: 2000,
  },
  {
    date: '2020-12-01',
    value: 2500,
  },
  {
    date: '2020-12-18',
    value: 4000,
  },
];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach((x) => {
  const key = x.date;
  if (map.has(key))
    map.set(key, { ...map.get(key), y: map.get(key).y + x.value });
  else
    map.set(key, {
      t: x.date,
      y: x.value,
    });
});
const ret = {
  label: [...map.keys()],
  data: [...map.values()],
};
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: I never used `new Map()` but I will learn more about it thanks for your answer.